# Javascript get value from swift

Tags: javascript, swift, uiwebview

I'm trying to get a value from swift using javascript. I'm using a IUWebView. I use this piece of Javascript to get the value:

```
var myVar = null;    

function getValue(key) {
    webkit.messageHandlers.getValue.postMessage(key);
    return myVar;
}
```

And this piece of Swift to return the value:

```
func userContentController(userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceiveScriptMessage message: WKScriptMessage) {
    if(message.name == "getValue") {
        if let value = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey(message.body as! String) {
            self.webView?.evaluateJavaScript("myVar = "+value+";", completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

The javascript code is calling the swift code correcly and the swift code is getting the value from the `NSUserDefaults` but the result isn't returned by the javascript function.

Can you help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you may be using a third party framework, but the stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(_:) method of UIWebview returns whatever is returned by the js function, as a String. So if your Javascript is

```
function doSomething() {
    return 'test'
}
```

Then you call `doSomething()` from iOS

```
let js = "doSomething()"
let result = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(js)
```

`result` should be a String with the value of `"test"`

**NOTE:** that something must be returned. I believe your code may not work because you are setting a value, not returning anything.